# How to Fix Sample App iOS done in Delphi that crash after splash

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

Fix Sample App iOS Delphi crash after splash
Delphi 10.4.2
Mac High Sierra 10.13.3

Trying to test in Simulator iPhone 6 Plus SDK 9.2

---

App starts in Simulador, show splash screen and then crash (closes)

My logs:

---

```
Jun  7 23:26:12 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: could not find icon for representation - com.apple.mobilephone
     Jun  7 23:26:12 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: could not find icon for representation - com.apple.mobilemail
     Jun  7 23:26:12 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: could not find icon for representation - com.apple.Music
     Jun  7 23:26:12 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: Reply Error: Connection interrupted
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Registered for possible future reinstall: (Header, file:///Users/jcgr/PAServer/scratch-dir/jcgr-10/Header.app/, {
     CFBundleIdentifier = Header;
     PackageType = Developer;
     SimulatorRootPath = "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot";
     SimulatorUserPath = "/Users/jcgr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C9BD6E6D-259E-4768-950F-3F670E7F0690/data";
     })
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac itunesstored[519]: libMobileGestalt MGBasebandSupport.c:60: _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45 (Operation not supported)
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac itunesstored[519]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac itunesstored[519]: libMobileGestalt MGBasebandSupport.c:189: No CT mobile equipment info dictionary while fetching kCTMobileEquipmentInfoIMEI
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Pasteboard change listener callback port NSMachPort: 0x7fc00bd0fd70 registered
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Requesting launch of Header with options: {
     environment =     {
     };
     }
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Beginning launch sequence for bundle 'Header'
     retryTimeout: 120.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge LaunchRetryTimeout value)
     bootTimeout: 300.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootRetryTimeout value)
     bootLeeway: 120.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootLeeway value)
     Note: Use 'xcrun simctl spawn booted defaults write domain key value' to modify defaults in the booted Simulator device.
     Simulator booted at: 2021-06-08 02:25:30 +0000
     Current time: 2021-06-08 03:26:13 +0000
     Within boot leeway: NO
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Launch attempt #0 for bundle 'Header', have been trying to launch for 0 seconds. Modern launch services = NO
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Got LSBundleProxy for 'Header', sequenceNumber 63, cacheGUID __NSConcreteUUID 0x7fc00e806fd0 BF5B2EDB-A9ED-48B7-BCA4-D99CA861CC07
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac assertiond[473]: assertion failed: 17D2047 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac CoreSimulatorBridge[475]: Launch successful for 'Header'
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.C9BD6E6D-259E-4768-950F-3F670E7F0690[450] (UIKitApplication:Header[0x754a][823]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: Application 'UIKitApplication:Header[0x754a]' crashed.
     Jun  7 23:26:13 Juans-Mac assertiond[473]: assertion failed: 17D2047 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
     Jun  7 23:26:14 Juans-Mac SpringBoard[469]: Reply Error: Connection interrupted
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YUP9tG9S

Comment: Simulator is not supported at present. It may be supported in a future version of Delphi

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Do you know which Delphi Ver.,  Mac OS, Xcode versions were the last that worked fine?
I mean what combination may I use in order to use IOS simulator
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can recall, I was able to use Delphi 10.2.3 with Xcode 10.3, that has iOS 10.3.2 Simulator, and macOS 10.14 (the OS on the Mac, not the SDK) or lower. It's been a while, though :-)

Comment: **Thanks a lot @DaveNottage**
Finally I could make it work following your last config.

Again: Thanks!!! @DaveNottage